# Getting a Windows batch file to execute an application in background and then execute the next statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having issue trying to get my Windows batch file to launch the Jetty web server in the background and then launch IE.  The current behavior is that after it started my Jetty web server, it doesn't return to launch IE.  It simply stuck there until I terminate the web server and then batch script will then proceed and launch IE.

Here's my batch script

```
SET JAVA_HOME=".\openjdk-1.8.0.141"
SET JETTY_HOME=".\jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531"

start /B cd /d "%~dp0" & %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw -DSTOP.PORT=8081 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -Djetty.base=%JETTY_HOME% -jar %JETTY_HOME%\start.jar

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8080/foo-tools
```

Can you spot anything obvious here?  I already used the 'start /B' to attempt to launch it in the background.  I have to change directory back to the current working directory, otherwise the variable that I set will not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that your script may launch "start cd", but the rest is executed as the next statement. What if you quote the whole start argument?

Comment: Did you try removing the `start /B` entirely and simply running `cd /d "%~dp0" &` + the rest of that line? Or even separating the `cd ` and the rest on two separate lines entirely (still without the `start /B`)? Or adding `/nowait` after the `/B`?

Comment: The first quoted parameter to a `start` becomes windowtitle. Add a dummy pair of double-quotes after the `/B` to provide a dummy window-title. The quotes in the `cd` command are not required. Enclose `cd...end` in a pair of quotes and move the quotes on the `set` statements from before the `=` to before the variablename. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Magoo, I tried to follow your suggestion, but no luck.

`start /B "" "cd /d %~dp0 & %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw -DSTOP.PORT=8081 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -Djetty.base=%JETTY_HOME% -jar %JETTY_HOME%\start.jar"`
`
When I run it, it give me an error pop up that says

`The system cannot find the file cd /d C:\Users\Foo\Desktop\Temp\Deliverables\foo-tools\ & .\openjdk-1.8.0.141\bin\javaw -DSTOP.PORT=8081 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -Djetty.base=.\jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531 -jar .\jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531\start.jar.`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify things and stipulate the script path with the `START`'s **`/D <Path>`** parameter?

```bat
SET "JAVA_HOME=openjdk-1.8.0.141"
SET "JETTY_HOME=jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531"

START "" /D "%~dp0" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" -DSTOP.PORT=8081 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -Djetty.base="%JETTY_HOME%" -jar "%JETTY_HOME%\start.jar"

START "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8080/foo-tools
```

I missed off `START`'s **`/B`** parameter because it was my understanding that `javaw.exe` doesn't open a CMD window anyhow. If my understanding is incorrect then please add it back just before `"%JAVA_HOME%`.

The `START` command for IE is only really necessary if you need the script again or don't want the cmd window to remain open.